# padding around hyperlinked images in email clients

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have a hyperlinked image and a paragraph as

```
<a href="#"><img src=""  align="right"/></a><p>Some text</p>
```

But this hyperlink is causing some padding on the paragraph in Outlook for the email.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Just to add, i believe display:block on the image may also sort this.

Comment: I had tried putting <img src="" alilgn="right" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0; display:block;" /> . However it would still leave  a padding at the top in Outlook.  I solved it by putting the paragraph and the image in 2 separate cells i.e <td><p></p></td>     <td><img src="" /></td> within a table. This removed the padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that when Writing html emails, you have to abandon all notion of good practice. Use tables and assume that the client will not understand css or not understand old html tags:

```
<table width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="#"><img src="" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​ 
I would recommend checking it in every browser and every client possible (hotmail, gmail ect in different browsers, thunderbird, outlook...)

Comment: Thanks, nothing like adding individual tables for the images. That always fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Styling HTML emails is a somewhat annoying process. Outlook only makes it more complicated as Outlook can appear very different from your classical web based email providers (yahoo, hotmail, gmail, etc.)

That said have you tried applying an inline style to your hyperlink?

```
<a style="padding:0; margin:0;" href="#">......
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding the padding:0; margin:0 to the link. That does not remove the padding from OUtlook 2007.  I have also tried adding a negative margin ,   margin:0 -6px; That too, does not help. SO basically it dents my paragraph by some pixels are disrupts the uniformity :(

Answer (score 0):

It's get fixed by adding a separate table for the images

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="x">
   <tr>
     <td><p>Some text goes here</p></td>
     <td><img src="picture.jpg" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```